# Its giving unexpected Indentation error.Any Idea ?Any one?

Tags: coffeescript

Below is my coffee Script .Its giving "Unexpected Indentation" error.
Any one can guess whats the errror is?

```
evaluateContainerRules: ( rules, containerType ) ->
    deferred = Ext.create( 'Deft.promise.Deferred' )

    searchCriteria = []
    for rule in rules
        if rule.searchTerms? and rule.searchTerms.length > 0
            searchCriteria.push( rule )
            console.log 'rule'
            console.log 'searchCriteria'

      if searchCriteria.length <= 0
             emptyRules = 
               [
              {
                 searchOption: 'EMPTY_RULE'
                searchTerms: true
        }
        ]
        console.log 'emptyRules'
        searchCriteria.push( emptyRules )
        searchCriteria.push["Hello"]
        console.log 'searchCriteria'

    store = Ext.create( 'Traverse.core.store.admin.container.ContainerMemberSummarySearchStore',
        params: 
            searchCriterias: searchCriteria
            traverseTypeEnums: if containerType is 'device' then [ Traverse.core.enumeration.TraverseType.DEVICE ] else [ Traverse.core.enumeration.TraverseType.TEST ]
    )
    complete = false
    store.on( 
        'load' 
        ( records, operation, success ) ->
            # NOTE: callback is fired multiple times for a paging store, only execute logic during the first call
            if complete
                return
            complete = true
            if success
                deferred.resolve( store )
            else
                store.destroyStore()
                @showError( operation.getError() )
                deferred.reject( operation.getError() )
            return
        scope: @
    )
    store.load()
    return deferred.promise
```

Its

Comment: Well, the second `if`-block seems completely mis-formatted. Between lines 11-18

Comment: Can you please help me with correctly formatted code.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a reasonable re-indentation of your code that compiles

```
evaluateContainerRules: ( rules, containerType ) ->
    deferred = Ext.create( 'Deft.promise.Deferred' )

    searchCriteria = []
    for rule in rules
        if rule.searchTerms? and rule.searchTerms.length > 0
            searchCriteria.push( rule )
            console.log 'rule'
            console.log 'searchCriteria'

        if searchCriteria.length <= 0
            emptyRules = 
                [{
                    searchOption: 'EMPTY_RULE'
                    searchTerms: true
                }]
        console.log 'emptyRules'
        searchCriteria.push( emptyRules )
        searchCriteria.push["Hello"]
        console.log 'searchCriteria'

    store = Ext.create( 'Traverse.core.store.admin.container.ContainerMemberSummarySearchStore',
        params: 
            searchCriterias: searchCriteria
            traverseTypeEnums: if containerType is 'device' then [ Traverse.core.enumeration.TraverseType.DEVICE ] else [ Traverse.core.enumeration.TraverseType.TEST ]
    )
    complete = false
    store.on( 
        'load' 
        ( records, operation, success ) ->
            # NOTE: callback is fired multiple times for a paging store, only execute logic during the first call
            if complete
                return
            complete = true
            if success
                deferred.resolve( store )
            else
                store.destroyStore()
                @showError( operation.getError() )
                deferred.reject( operation.getError() )
            return
        scope: @
    )
    store.load()
```

Hope this helps